# Tensorflow behavior: gradient computation across multi-GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent, multi-gpu

I am trying to compute global mean and global variance for batch normalization layer across GPUs, both forward and backward should be considered.
With `\sigma^2 = mean(x^2) - mean(x)^2`, the gradient w.r.t. each `x` can be computed independently in the GPU that `x` is attached to.

However, when computing the gradients, I met a problem: without specifying GPU device, `tf.gradient` will use the `\gpu:0`.
I cannot specify each operation of gradient computation because the gradients are computed automatically by the `optimizer` and only gradients of parameters are computed.

My question is that if a node is explicitly attached to a GPU device, why the gradient can not be attached to the same GPU device?

I tried this code and get two timeline files [timelines.zip](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/files/1649923/timelines.zip) and two snapshots bellow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

N_SAMPLES = 100000000


def all_reduce(gpu_num):
    means = []
    x2s = []
    axs = []
    for i in range(gpu_num):
        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[N_SAMPLES], name='local_input_%d' % i)
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d'%i):
            ax = tf.multiply(10.0, x, name='local_multiply_%d'%i)
            mean = tf.reduce_mean(ax, name='local_mean_%d'%i)
            x2 = tf.square(ax, name='local_square_%d'%i)
            axs.append(ax)
            means.append(mean)
            x2s.append(x2)

    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        global_mean = tf.reduce_mean(means, name='global_mean')
        global_var = tf.subtract(tf.reduce_mean(x2s, name='global_x2'),
                                 tf.square(global_mean, name='global_mean_square'),
                                 name='global_sub')
        print global_var.get_shape()

    gs = []
    # manually
    # for i in range(gpu_num):
    #     with tf.device('/gpu:%d'%i):
    #         gradient_wrt_mean = tf.gradients(global_mean, axs[i])
    #         gradient_wrt_var = tf.gradients(global_var, axs[i])
    #         gs.append(gradient_wrt_mean)
    #         gs.append(gradient_wrt_var)

    # auto by tf
    gradient_wrt_mean = tf.gradients(global_mean, axs)
    gradient_wrt_var = tf.gradients(global_var, axs)
    gs.append(gradient_wrt_var)
    gs.append(gradient_wrt_mean)

    for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
        print [n.name, n.device]

    return global_mean, global_var, axs, gs


def main(_):
    gpu_num = 2
    mean_op, var_op, xs, gs = all_reduce(gpu_num)
    x = np.random.randn(N_SAMPLES*gpu_num)
    print np.mean(x), np.var(x)
    feed_dict = dict()
    for i in range(gpu_num):
        feed_dict[xs[i]] = x[i*N_SAMPLES:(i+1)*N_SAMPLES]

    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=False)
    config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False, gpu_options=gpu_options)
    sess = tf.Session(config=config)

    # mean, var, g = sess.run([
    #     mean_op, var_op, gs
    # ], feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
    # print mean, var

    g = sess.run([
        gs
    ], feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

    # Create the Timeline object, and write it to a json
    tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
    ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
    with open('timeline.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(ctf)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Two figures:
auto, without specifying GPU device.
[image]

manually specifying GPU device.
[image]

If using `tf.gradient` without specifying GPU devices, only a `tf.reduce_mean` operation is done in `/gpu:1`. So is there some easy way that the operations of gradient computation can be assigned automatically to the corresponded GPU device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered from github:

```
tf.gradients(
ys,
xs,
grad_ys=None,
name='gradients',
colocate_gradients_with_ops=False,
gate_gradients=False,
aggregation_method=None,
stop_gradients=None
)
```

colocate_gradients_with_ops: If True, try colocating gradients with the corresponding op.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16328#issuecomment-359899310